# Royal versus Loyal

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

One of the online English-learning sites in Japan where I study English, regularly uses the expression "Royal customers" instead of "Loyal customers" in their address. I felt it strange, so I advised them that maybe it was a typo which should be corrected. However, they answered that they intentionally use "Royal" saying that the word 'Loyal' might have a negative effect on their reputation.

They felt that using 'loyal' made their customers think the company is not respectful enough, that the company didn't care about them, and that customers would think they were simply subordinates or slaves, forced to buy the company's services as if they have no choice, all due to the connotation of the word 'loyal'.

By adopting the word 'royal,' instead of 'loyal,' I think they thought they were showing admiration and respect to their customers. I guess they also thought that 'Royal' was phonetically superior to 'Loyal' because it uses an 'R' instead of an "L".

Hearing their explanation, I felt they were only trying to cover up their confusion in the use of these two words. After asking some native English speakers about this I concluded that the company's reason for using this form of address was more to protect their pride as an English-education business.

None of the native English speakers I'd asked agreed with the company's reasoning. Some advised "valued customers" as a useful alternative and a perfect choice for the company to adopt, if they really wanted to express their respect and gratitude to their customers.
I'd like to hear your opinions. Is there any thinkable reason to address customers as "royal" in the way the company asserted, or do you think the company's remarks are persuasive?

Anyway, I'm dissatisfied with the company's strange reasoning and tactics and wonder why they made excuses for their form of address? Do you think they never considered using "valued customers," as an English education company?

Would any of you address customers as "Royal customers," not "Loyal customers," if you were in the customer service department of your company?
Thank you

Comment: Does the organization have any brand identity that trades in the trappings of monarchy?  Crowns in the logos, goofy royalist puns in the product names offered, etc?  As a real world example, Royal Caribbean cruise line has a loyalty program named "Crown & Anchor Society"

Comment: They are off their rocker. “Loyal” has no such connotations.  If they wish to treat their customers like kings and queens they can use royal. If they wish to make reference to their customers repeated patronage (possibly in the face of other options) they should be using loyal.

Comment: One of the risks of using "royal" is that if they said something like "We offer this service to our royal customers" then I'd assume that they literally meant royalty, and that the offer didn't apply to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about the culture of a particular company rather than a more general question about English usage.

Comment: Royal, in this case, seems to be an overstatement or exaggeration. Not factually correct.  But, often good marketing.

Comment: The usage is imperious.

Comment: Closure of this question because answers may be a matter of opinion is not justified. The answer depends clearly on the defined meanings of royal and loyal, and to a lesser extent on the possibility of a typo, on the possible phonetic confusion of l and r, and on the usage of native speakers. These are not mere matters of opinion.

Comment: I can't help but hear the racist *Rocks of Ruck* and *Flied Lice* in the confusion of R with L.

Answer (score 1):

> Royal = belonging or connected to a king or queen or a member of their family:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/royal)

Another usage is illustrated by

> Royal = good or excellent, as if intended for or typical of royalty:
> “The team was given a royal reception/welcome.”
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/royal)

The company is suggesting that it has *Royal* customers, in the sense that they are members of a royal family. If there are no such customers, this is wrong, and misrepresents the company’s status; it is certainly dishonest or misleading representation and in some legislations may be illegal.

To describe customers (other than any members of a royal family) as royal is simply wrong. If the intention is to persuade customers that they will receive *royal* attention in the sense of the second definition, it is the attention that is royal, not the customer.

The use of *royal* is, apart from the small chance that there are real royal customers, inappropriate and misleading.

> Loyal = firm and not changing in your friendship with or support for a person or an organization, or in your belief in your principles:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loyal)

This definition of loyal includes no meaning of subservience or dependency. It is based on the idea that the company is so good that it attracts loyalty.

In summary, I agree with you and those whom you consulted. I would not trust this company to be a good source of English tuition.